# how to hide external video controls from clients

Tags: bigbluebutton

I'm using BigBlueButton in my website,
the problem is:
we can't stream our videos online in BigBlueButton and all of our visitors can stop/play/... our uploaded external video for themselves.

so we are looking for a solution to display a video as a live stream.
our video is in .mp4 format.

what we are thinking to remove play/stop/... buttons from video so our clients can't stop the video and play it for them.

Comment: Please formulate explicitly what your question is? Do you want to get the BigBlueButton to work, or are you looking for an advice on which video player to use?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of bigbluebutton that nearly would have a final release (v2.4), visitors (viewers) can't pause, stop, ... the playing video.